# "File or Directory not found" IIS 7

Tags: iis-7

I have added an application on IIS 7 and the physical path selected correctly.

However, I got this problem when browsing the application:

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. the problem is also when I tried it like this: http://abc.com/default.aspx

but if I tried it with: http://abc.com/myimage.png => works

the server has installed .NET Framework 2.0, and also 4.0

Any idea what is wrong here?

THanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the Default Document set to your homepage correctly?

Comment: Can you confirm that Default.aspx works when you browse to it directly?

Comment: no, .aspx does not work. the rest like image files (png, jpg), js files are working.

Comment: Have you added an Application to it and checked that the ASP and made sure it is set to the proper ASP.Net library (like 2.0 or 4.0)?

Comment: probably, this is the problem. the server installed both asp.net 2.0 and 4.0. How can I make sure that it is set to the asp.net library 2.0 or 4.0?

Comment: You choose this when you create your application.  After you have added your application, you can change it.  Right click website --> Manage Application --> Advanced Settings: Application Pool

Comment: it is 2.0 at the moment I think it should be working as the web app is is using .net 3.5

Comment: @olidev, what did this end up being?

Answer (score 1):

One solution:
Try to add the type to IIS Mime types. Ex: I meet this error when try to click a mkv video file.

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Selection "MIME Type" feature
3. Add...
4. Enter this content
   File name extension: mkv
   Mime types: mkv/mkv
5. OK
6. Restart the website
   Click the file again, its worked